# Need help to add swipe functionality using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to see if I can add swipe functionality for mobile devices to a website using only Javascript.

Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script>

var x1;
var y1;
var x2;
var y2;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  x1 = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  y1 = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
  x2 = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  y2 = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
  if(y1 > y2){
    alert("up");
  }else{
    alert("down");
  }
});

</script>
</html>
```

So the code works fine and it can tell the difference between swiping up and down, but my problem is that if I add this code to my site, then it doesn't allow me to do anything but run this code. So for example if I try to touch a button it wont work and the screen will just alert "up" or "down". I just want to have this code run when I swipe up or down from the footer to expand it.

I have tried replacing

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
```

With

```
document.getElementById("footer").addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
```

But then nothing works?

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Have you tried getting the position of the start and match it to `el.getBoundingClientRect(​)` to check whether it should be handled?

Comment: Let me try this, and ill get back to you